# Grep in new log files as they are created

Tags: grep, logs, filenames

Every hour  the server creates a new log file in the format of syslog_all.yyyy-mm-dd-hh and archives the file from the previous hour.

What I need is a way to grep through the current and yet-to-be-created log files for a certain string without having to re-start the command every hour just because the filename has changed.

Currently I do:

`tail -f syslog_all.2017-04-25-09 | egrep -i --line-buffered "string1" | egrep -i "(.*first.*|.*second.*|.*third.*)"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a high level recipe.

1. Configure syslogd or rsyslogd (whichever your system uses) to output
   the required facility/priority messages to a named pipe in addition
   to where it goes now. Extract from `man rsyslog.conf`

> ```
> Named pipes
>
>    This  version  of  rsyslogd(8) has support for logging output to
>    named pipes (fifos). A fifo or named pipe can be used as a  des‐
>    tination  for  log messages by prepending a pipe symbol ('|') to
>    the name of the file. This is handy for debugging. Note that the
>    fifo  must  be  created  with the mkfifo(1) command before rsys‐
>    logd(8) is started.
> ```

There is an example in my `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn       |/tmp/rt_monitor
```

2. Create a named pipe and use tail and grep to read and search from the pipe.

   `mkfifo /tmp/rt_monitor; tail -f /tmp/rt_monitor | grep "alert string"`

You should check that system continues if named pipe becomes full if you do not have your consumer running and prevent this from occuring, I've given you a very crued recipe.

Comment: I cannot change how the syslog works. I can only access the log files :(